# How to use the Class decorator wrapper?

Tags: python, decorator

I have a `data_class` object and want to add some functionality using a decorator.
It works, however the class name is lost and becomes `defaultinstance.<locals>.SubClass` .

I know `functools.wraps` can fix this, but where/how should it be used?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields, is_dataclass
   
def defaultinstance(object):
  
    class SubClass(object):
        @classmethod
        def woof(cls):
            print("woof")

    return SubClass


@defaultinstance
@dataclass
class Dog:
    name: str
    paws: int


doggo = Dog(name="jack", paws=4)

print(doggo)
# defaultinstance.<locals>.SubClass(name='jack', paws=4)
```

Comment: Do you mean functools.wraps? [If so the example in the python documentation might help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)

Comment: yes, `wraps`. I see examples for using it for functions, but not for classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just have the decorator modify the class like this

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields, is_dataclass
   
def defaultinstance(object):
    """
    creates a class method 'woof' and adds it to object
    """
    @classmethod
    def woof(cls):
        print("woof")
    
    setattr(object, 'woof', woof)
    return object


@defaultinstance
@dataclass
class Dog:
    name: str
    paws: int


doggo = Dog(name="jack", paws=4)

print(doggo)
Dog.woof()  # as it's a class method we can use it directly on Dog
doggo.woof()  # but it works fine on doggo too
```

with result

```
Dog(name='jack', paws=4)
woof
woof
```

This way you don't have to create a new class that would need to masquerade as the old class with the old class never being used.

Comment: It would help if you show the usage of the `woof` method on `doggo`

Comment: Yeah good call, I've added it's use on both Dog and doggo

Comment: the original code in the question is basically adding a new type on top of the "Dog" type, resulting in changing/masking the type then?

Comment: excellent answer. I assumed I needed a class to be able to use a `classmethod`, but I see that in this case it can be used in a function.

Comment: @DaemonPainter The original code took the class <Dog>, created a new class, <SubClass>, that inherited from <Dog>, and stored <SubClass> in the variable Dog

Comment: I feel like this is an important remark to do, thanks for explaining it!